# Problems Adding Records VB .Net

Tags: vb.net

good day to all... i was having a hard time figuring out what's the problem on my code

My code for Add records button is actually working, "BUT" the problem is

• After putting incorrect Data on Text the error will occur over and over again even though i have already inputted the correct data..

```
   Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Charles\Documents\Database1.accdb")
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim dt As DataTable
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        fillListView()
    End Sub
    Private Sub fillListView()
        conn.Open()
        With cmd
            .Connection = conn
            .CommandText = "Select * From Employee"
        End With
        ListView1.Items.Clear()
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While dr.Read
            With ListView1
                .Items.Add(dr.Item(0))
                With .Items(.Items.Count - 1).SubItems
                    .Add(dr(1))
                    .Add(dr(2))
                    .Add(dr(3))
                    .Add(dr(4))
                    .Add(dr(5))
                End With
            End With
        End While
        conn.Close()
    End Sub
    Public Sub clearAll()
        txtName.Clear()
        txtSSS.Clear()
        txtTIN.Clear()
        txtSalary.Clear()
    End Sub
    Private Sub ListView1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListView1.Click
        txtName.Text = ListView1.SelectedItems.Item(0).SubItems(1).Text
        txtSSS.Text = ListView1.SelectedItems.Item(0).SubItems(2).Text
        txtTIN.Text = ListView1.SelectedItems.Item(0).SubItems(3).Text
        txtTIN.Text = ListView1.SelectedItems.Item(0).SubItems(5).Text
    End Sub
    Public Sub enableTxtBox()
        txtName.Enabled = True
        txtSSS.Enabled = True
        txtTIN.Enabled = True
        dtpED.Enabled = True
        txtSalary.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Public Sub disableTxtBox()
        txtName.Enabled = False
        txtSSS.Enabled = False
        txtTIN.Enabled = False
        dtpED.Enabled = False
        txtSalary.Enabled = False
    End Sub
    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        enableTxtBox()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClose_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click
        Dim Response As Integer
        Response = MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to exit?", "", _
        MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
        If Response = vbYes Then
            Me.Close()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
        Try
            conn.Open()
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Employee(EmployeeName,SSS,TIN,ED,Salary) Values(@EmployeeName,@SSS,@TIN,@ED,@Salary)"
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeName", txtName.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SSS", txtSSS.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TIN", txtTIN.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ED", dtpED.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Salary", txtSalary.Text)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            conn.Close()
            fillListView()
            clearAll()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error")
        End Try

    End Sub
    End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: Could you also add the error message/stack trace of whatever the error is?

Comment: He has no idea what the error is. All he gets is a MsgBox that unhelpfully says "Error", no matter what goes wrong. A good lesson in why you shouldn't swallow exceptions, *especially* while debugging.

Comment: Thank sir.. just edited my question and put all the necessary codes. just started coding VB yesterday so i don't much of an idea sorry and thanks again

Comment: I didn't mean that you needed more code. I mean that you need to remove the pointless Try/Catch block that swallows the exception and displays a message box instead. If you just started coding VB yesterday, where did you learn the bad habit of swallowing all exceptions in a Catch block?

Comment: Just by reading and searching at google sir..

Comment: Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error")
        End Try
just change "Error" to ex and you will see the error

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you don't see an error message like you should is because you're not using `Exceptions` at all.

In this part of code:

```
Catch ex As Exception
   MsgBox("Error")
End Try
```

You have declared `Exception` but you have actually never used it.
To call `Exception` you should write that part of code like this:

```
Catch ex As Exception
   MsgBox(ex.message)
End Try
```

Now you can see that if you get into `Catch` in `MsgBox` Exception will show up and **you will be able to read actual error**.

Comment: That will generate a `System.ArgumentException`, you should use `MsgBox(ex.Message)`.

Comment: Thanks @TheBlueDog I totally forgot about Message part

Comment: I think i know what the problem is... but just to be sure i'll enumerate what i've noticed

• i can only add 1 set of data.. if i tried to save another set of data error will Occur "COM Object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used"

• tried clicking the save button again and "The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is Open"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Everyone i've just solved my problem...

fixed my code for fillListiew()

```
Private Sub fillListView()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    ds.Tables.Add(dt)

    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Employee", conn)
    da.Fill(dt)
    ListView1.Items.Clear()
    Dim newRow As DataRow
    For Each newRow In dt.Rows
        ListView1.Items.Add(newRow.Item(0))
        ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(newRow(1))
        ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(newRow(2))
        ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(newRow(3))
        ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(newRow(4))
        ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(newRow(5))
    Next
End Sub
```